# react-select if value is selected keep focus border color

Tags: reactjs, colors, border, react-select, selected

In react-select how can I keep the focus border color if value is selected?

now I have the following config

```
const selectCustomStylesCheckboxes = {
  control: (base, state) => ({
    ...base,
    boxShadow: state.isFocused ? 0 : 0,
    borderWidth: 2,
    minHeight: 50,
    borderColor: state.isFocused ? "#707070" : base.borderColor,
    "&:hover": {
      borderColor: state.isFocused ? "#707070" : base.borderColor
    }
  }),
  option: (provided, state) => ({
    ...provided,
    color: state.isSelected ? "#46b428" : "initial",
    //margin: "0 10px",
    fontWeight: "500",
    backgroundColor: state.isSelected ? "rgba(70, 180, 40, 0.18)" : "initial"
  }),
  menuPortal: base => ({ ...base, zIndex: 9999 })
};
```

[image]

but I don't know how to track state selected

Comment: Could you provide the full code or an online demo? Which may help others to catch up with the problem you are facing quickly.

Comment: focus works but I want to keep the focus border color if value is selected something like this `borderColor: state.isSelected ? "#707070" : base.borderColor,`

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to manage my issue with Control component:

```
const Control = (props) => {
  const selected = props.hasValue ? "has-option" : "";
  return (
    <div className={selected}>
      <components.Control
        {...props}
        classNamePrefix={selected}
      ></components.Control>
    </div>
  );
};
```

than I adjust via CSS the border color

```
  .has-option {
      [class$="-control"] {
          border-color: $gray;
      }

      [class$="-IndicatorsContainer"] {
          svg {
              fill: $gray;
          }
      }
  }
```